# Registering domain during Christmas holidays

Tags: domain-registration

One of the domain names I tried to register previously has been blocked by a domain grabber two days prior to my own attempt. That was about 1 year ago. The attempt to buy the domain from that person failed due to a totally exaggerated price. So I dropped the issue and watched the domain (offered at sedo.com). As expected there were no more offers, the domain was not sold.

Now I learn from the whois database that the registration of that domain name ends on 25 Dec 2012 (Christmas holiday). This raises two questions for me, I fail to find reliable answers on the internet. So maybe someone experienced here can drop a statement or a hint:

1. Is it reasonable that the domain name in question really will be free again when that date mentioned in the whois database up to when the domain is registered has passed? I certainly know that the registration can be prolonged, that is not what I mean. I expect (hope) that that domain grabber does *not* extend the registration, since it costs money and effort and he failed to sell the domain. Provided this is the case and the domain registration is not prolonged, is that date mentioned reliable? Or might it just be some 'default' date?
2. I would like to *try* to register that domain name as soon as it is unregistered. Since that domain grabber registered that domain only two days before my own registration attempt I would like to prevent such annoying interference next time. So I ask myself: is it possible to register a domain name on a holiday? I mean not to send an email to my provider to do so on that day or before, but to actually have to process taking place as not to wait for 1-2 days after the unregistration? My own provider which I am very happy with does not offer such service on a holiday (which is perfectly understandable). They are 'still checking' if they can offer something automatic. I researched and did not find an answer to the question if that is possible *at all*. Is an automatic registration attempt on a holiday possible? Where can I do that? Is that reliable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 - Certainly from my own experience, that date is not reliable. I have personally watched a domain daily, which the date was set to expire september 14th, and up until september 30th, it still displayed the same information. The day after it was renewed. So no, that information is not reliable.

You can use services such as this [Domain Notification Tool](http://www.domaintools.com/monitor/domain-monitor/) that will let you know when the domain name is available.

2 - I really don't see why that would be a problem, but i'm not sure. Try contacting other domain registrars to find out. I would believe that since everything is automatic, it wouldn't be a problem, but i can't speak for sure.

Comment: Now that you write your own experience I remember having read about some 'grace period' when domain registrations run out. So that you can still react as owner and renew the registration even after it has expired. Does make sene somehow... And thanks for the hint with that NOtification Tool. Didn't know that one. I contacted 4 web space provideres, all replied that automatic registration is not offered. Might be different when adressing registrars directly, but that is pretty expensive, as far as I know...

Comment: That might be correct, but i can't really tell you. I know my domains are set to expire exactly a year after renewal, but of course, i have never waited over a year to find out. Hopefully somebody else can give you a better answer on that.